# Notepad++ Help Possibly Using Regex?

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++, and I need to take a part of many different lines of text, that are pretty similar, and put them in another line.

Here's an example of what I have

```
    - '@AND b $testing123.<playeruuid> = false'
    - '@AND b $thisisatest.<playeruuid> = false'
```

and I want to turn that into

```
    - '@AND b $testing123.<playeruuid> = false'
    - '@SETBOOL $<playeruuid>.name testing123'
    - '@AND b $thisisatest.<playeruuid> = false'
    - '@SETBOOL $<playeruuid>.name thisisatest'
```

I was thinking of using a find/replace regular expression to do something like this:

Find:

```
    - '@AND b $x.<playeruuid> = false'
```

and Replace with:

```
    - '@AND b $x.<playeruuid> = false'
    - '@SETBOOL $<playeruuid>.name x'
```

Of course this isn't in regex format, but this is what I'm trying to do, and I don't know where to start.

So in summary, I want to take a part of a pattern and stick it into another line of text, but in bulk?

I'm not exactly sure how to explain it well. I'm very sorry for the lack of detail.

Comment: Contrary to the close vote, I don't think the question is too broad.  It would just require some careful use of regex matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using find and replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
    - '@AND b \$(.*)?\.(<.*?>) = false'
```

**Replace:**

```
    - '@AND b \$$1.$2 = false'\n    - '@SETBOOL \$$2\.name ($1)'
```

The quantities in parentheses are called *capture groups*, because the regex engine captures which is contained in them while matching.  The capture groups can then be used in the replacement as `$1`, for the first capture, or `$2`, for the second capture.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: This repmove the orignal line (`@AND...`), but it must be kept (add `$0\n` at the begining of the replace part)